# Required DLLs when delivering a MFC - App

Tags: dll, mfc

I can´t find which DLLs must be delivered to start my application without installing the mfc runtime. There are no information in the internet.

By trying on a Testsystem i found out, that I will need MFC71u.dll, msvcp71.dll and msvcr71.dll.

Are there other ones?

Comment: [Redistributing the MFC Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235264.aspx) and [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx).

Comment: [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com) is your friend.

Comment: @ymett: *Dependency Walker* will miss modules that are loaded as a result of [Run-Time Dynamic Linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685090.aspx).

Comment: Re: `"There are no information in the internet."` - that's funny :))

Comment: @IInspectable Actually, dependency walker does handle this by application profiling (also, good luck to anyone that wants to try to use LoadLibrary to hook into MFC!).

Comment: @RogerRowland: Profiling is nice, if you can prove to have 100% code coverage. Good luck with that. If I'm not mistaken, the ODBC drivers use late-binding (i.e. run-time dynamic linking).

Comment: @IInspectable I'm referring to the "Application profiling" feature of dependency walker, in case of doubt, but you're right that 100% code coverage is necessary to catch everything. AFAIK, ODBC drivers have nothing to do with MFC anyway, not sure of your point here?

Comment: @RogerRowland: From my first comment [Redistributing the MFC Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235264.aspx): *"If your application uses the MFC database classes (for example, [CRecordset Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92bcy0kw.aspx) and [CRecordView Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/133zc1xb.aspx)), you must redistribute ODBC and any ODBC drivers that your application uses."*

Comment: @IInspectable Ok, gotcha, and your first comment is spot on BTW and should probably have been an answer, even if a short one.

Comment: You want to deliver (the MFC runtime) DLLs with your app but do not want to install the MFC runtime? What is the difference between delivering the MFC runtime DLLs and installing them? Why don't you install the MFC runtime as MS requires you to do?

Comment: @WernerHenze: There is no requirement imposed by Microsoft, that you must install redistributable packages. See [Choosing a Deployment Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235316.aspx), specifically: *"Local deployment [...] You can use this deployment method to enable installation by users who don't have administrator rights, or for applications that can be run from a network share."*